# Modular XML Schema - How should I do it?

Tags: xml, xsd, modularity

I am very new to xml and xml schema. I want do code something quite modular and I have difficulties achieving this modularity.

My problem is the following: I want xml-schemas which validate the following xml file:

```
<process  xmlns="http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/default"
      xmlns:bpmn="http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/bpmn" xmlns:bpel="http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/bpel" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/default http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/default.xsd http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/bpmn http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/bpmn.xsd http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/bpel http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/bpel.xsd">
  <bpmn:processProperties>
    <bpmn:uri>http://soa.lotterm.org/repository/stocktrade/stockmarket.bpmn</bpmn:uri>
  </bpmn:processProperties>
  <bpel:processProperties>
    <bpel:uri>http://soa.lotterm.org/repository/stocktrade/stockmarket.bpmn</bpmn:uri>
  </bpel:processProperties>
</process>
```

Why did I create such a XML-File?

Well I need a default structure, where there are artifacts (e.g. process elements). These artifacts should be able to store module-specific properties (e.g. from my bpel or bpmn module). The default schema of course doesn't know of these modules and the modules don't know of one another (just the default schema). How will my schema look which supports this xml-file?

All of my attempts (e.g. with extension of an abstract property type) don't work out.

Edit: When I try to generate the schema it isn't what I am looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/default" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="process" type="def:processType" xmlns:def="http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/default"/>
  <xs:complexType name="processType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="bpmn:processProperties" xmlns:bpmn="http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/bpmn"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And the bpmn-namespace schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/bpmn" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="processProperties" type="bpmn:processPropertiesType" xmlns:bpmn="http://soa.lotterm.org/spec/test/bpmn"/>
  <xs:complexType name="processPropertiesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="uri"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Well now what is the problem with that? Well the default schema needs to know that the bpmn namespace has processProperties. That's now what I want. Now you will probably suggest to add a process to the bpmn schema which extends the process from the default schema. That's also not what I want because I want to be able to extend the process from different namespaces. So it could look like the one I mentioned earlier.

How can I achieve this?

Cheers, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried auto-generating a schema from this instance using one of the many schema generation tools available? Given the simplicity of this input, I would think they will do a reasonable job.

In XSD you have to have at least one schema document per target namespace. Since none of your namespaces has more than two elements in it, this would seem to be quite modular enough for your purposes. If it's not modular enough, you need to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: OK, it seems your question is not about modularity at all, but about extensibility. Perhaps you want a schema that validates some large class of documents of which this is one example. Or perhaps you want a family of schemas which validate different subclasses of this large class of documents. You can't describe that large class by showing one example instance; so try to define your requirements more clearly in prose.